# How to navigate to a section on postback?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have multiple sections on my aspx page.

```
<ul>
<li class="tab-current"><asp:HyperLink ID="home" runat="server" Text="Home" NavigateUrl="#section-1"/></li>
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="events" runat="server" Text="Events" NavigateUrl="#section-2"/></li>
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="finance" runat="server" Text="Finance" NavigateUrl="#section-3"/></li>
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="merchandise" runat="server" Text="Merchandise" NavigateUrl="#section-4"/></li>
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="tasks" runat="server" Text="Tasks" NavigateUrl="#section-5"/></li>
<li><asp:HyperLink ID="profile" runat="server" Text="Profile" NavigateUrl="#section-6"/></li>
</ul>
```

On one of the sections I have a button and a gridview control. On button click gridview gets loaded with some data, However button click causes postback and takes me Section#1. I want to stay on the that gridview after postback.

Thanks.

Comment: Could do with seeing more of your code to better understand what you are doing.

Why don't you use Anchor Tags <a> instead of the ASP.NET HyperLink control?

Comment: Okay. I have changed the ASP.NET Hyperlink control to Anchor Tag <a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` to the Page directive.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="myPage.aspx.cs" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Or if you want this for all your pages you could set in the Web.Config under the `<system.web>` node.

```
<pages validateRequest="true" maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always"/>
```

**UPDATE**

To make sure the correct tab is displayed after PostBack, you need to call a client side function.

First add something like this to the section `onclick="setTabIndex(1)"`. This can also be `onmouseover`, a binding on class name etc.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTabIndex(tab) {
        //store the tab number in a hidden field so you can access it in code behind
        document.getElementById("<% = HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = tab;
    }

    function showTab(tab) {
        alert(tab);
        //open the correct tab
    }
</script>
```

And in code behind call the client side function `showTab`:

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showTab", "showTab(" + HiddenField1.Value + ")", true);
        }
```

Comment: Adding `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` doesn't navigate to the section

Comment: No it doesn't. It goes to the same position of the button that was clicked. After postback everything after the `#` is removed. And in your question you are talking about "postback takes me to Section#1" and here "doesn't navigate to the section". Which is it?

Comment: Okay. The thing is, I have multiple Sections <section id="section-id"> on my page. In <section id="section-2">, I have a button. On clicking the button a gridview is loaded. But when it happens I am taken to the first section. These sections are tabs on my page. I will update the question.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to pass back the url of the current page with the section ID anchor appended to the URL (see below).

Example:

- http://yoursite.com/return-address#section1
- http://yoursite.com/return-address#section2

and so on...

Hope this helps.

Craig

Comment: How would passing the section ID in query string make any difference? Can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Because on page load it would jump to the section tagged with that ID. Try it out and see what I mean. Cheers